# Building a query string in php variable

Tags: php

I am learning how.. but failing....
When I run this query I get all the products for the product type entered.

```
   $productchk = "SELECT products"
   . " from products"
   . " WHERE active = '0' and product_type = '" . [v_product_type] .  "'";
```

but I need to add the following:

```
order by product Limit 1
```

to the query and I have tried . " I keep getting syntax errors.

I thought that by adding it before the `".";` on the end of statement would work but it  doesnt..

Any thoughts?

Also.. what would you look up on the internet to learn about creating statements like this?

Comment: `[v_product_type]` -> `$v_product_type`? Also checkout [prepared statements](http://us3.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

Comment: Please give actual error messages.

Comment: Use ' instead of " when you don't have any variables between " ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$productchk = "SELECT products"
   . " FROM products"
   . " WHERE active = '0' AND product_type = '" . $v_product_type .  "'"
   . " ORDER BY product LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

The last ' closes the value of *product_type*, so if you insert stuff there, it gets interpreted as part of that value. Append after "'" but before the closing ";".

Effectively:

```
  $productchk = "SELECT products"
   . " from products"
   . " WHERE active = '0' and product_type = '" . [v_product_type] .  "'"
   . " order by product Limit 1";
```

Also, please **use stored procedures and prepared statements**! It's 1. faster, 2. much safer, 3. less escaping